# launch Netbeans 10 with command on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, netbeans

I'm trying to launch netbeans  typing "netbeans" command but doesn't work

I've created a symbolinc link  from the netbeans launch script in /bin

```
sudo ln -s netbeans /bin/netbeans
```

But I can't launch netbeans with "netbeans" command

Comment: That doesn't seem right, you trying to link `netbeans` command to `/bin/netbeans` so you can run netbeans with `netbeans` ? I think you have mistype

Comment: You can rather try aliases.